# Подскажите пожалуйста бесплатные книги по C и C++

Tags: c++, c, книги

Подскажите пожалуйста бесплатные книги по C и C++. Нужны именно бесплатные, не спераченые, а именно официально бесплатные по С и С++. И желательно что бы с официального сайта можно было скачать но это не обязательно. Повторюсь именно БЕСПЛАТНЫЕ если такие вообще есть. Спасибо

Comment: А они там официально бесплатные?

Comment: Нет, не дубликат мне нужны бесплатные.

Comment: Поиск книг или чего бы то ни было - на данном сайте оффтоп, кроме специально созданных "каноничных" вопросов-ответов. Отдельный вопрос под БЕСПЛАТНЫЕ книги заводить нет смысла.

Comment: Кстати, обратите внимание на описание метки [tag:книги], которую вы добавили к вопросу.

Comment: Спасибо поправил и да извините не обратил внимания

Comment: Дело не в метке, а в тематике вопроса. От того, что вы убрали метку, вопрос не стал менее оффтопичным.

Comment: @insolor А вы уверены, что оффтоп? На агло-SO да, оффтоп, а здесь вроде бы нет.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, уверен. Вот ссылки на вопросы на Мете: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2075/1365, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/1365

Comment: @insolor Может я чего-то не увидел? Я не вижу там однозначного решения, что это оффтопик. К тому же, это не внесено в правила и в список причин закрытия вопроса.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, действительно, не совсем то. Вот ссылка на правила: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic `"Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать: ... Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию."`

Comment: @insolor Мм, точно. Пардон, не увидел раньше.

Comment: В принципе я получил то что хотел, больше всего понравился ответ @Alexander Petrov. Но что теперь делать с этим вопросом? Удалять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Официально бесплатные книги:

[на английском](https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md#c-1)

[на русском](https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books-ru.md#c-1)

Answer (score 3):

[Столяров](http://www.stolyarov.info/), например. «Введение в C++», «Программирование: введение в профессию». Официально бесплатны в электронном виде.

Answer (score 1):

Мне больше всего понравилась книга  - Стивен Прата "C++ primer plus", так же у этого автора есть книги просто по Си.

Comment: В бесплатном доступе официально эта книга есть?

Comment: официально нет, можно скачать на торрентах